# Exception while trying to run Spark app with JSON parsing

Tags: scala, jackson, sbt, apache-spark, jackson-modules

I have a simple Spark application with Scala and SBT. First I tried to do the following:

- run `sbt clean package`
- run `spark-submit --class Main ./target/scala-2.11/sparktest_2.11-1.0.jar`

but it fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/DefaultScalaModule$
```

Then I tried the assembly plugin for SBT, but I got the following exception instead:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.addField(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedField;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyName;ZZZ)V
```

As I can see, everything looks related to the Jackson lib and to the Scala support. Maybe it's some issue related to versions of the libraries?

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "SparkTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8", "-feature")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-core"           % "1.2.1"     % "provided",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"    % "jackson-core"          % "2.4.1",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"    % "jackson-databind"      % "2.4.1",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module"  %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.4.1"
  )
}
```

And my application code is simply this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

trait JsonUtil {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
}

case class Person(name: String)

object Main extends JsonUtil {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Test App")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val inputFile = "/home/user/data/person.json"
    val input = sc.textFile(inputFile)

    val persons = input.flatMap { line ⇒ {
      try {
        println(s"  [DEBUG] trying to parse '$line'")
        Some(mapper.readValue(line, classOf[Person]))
      } catch {
        case e : Exception ⇒
          println(s"  [EXCEPTION] ${e.getMessage}")
          None
      }
    }}

    println("PERSON LIST:")
    for (p ← persons) {
      println(s"  $p")
    }
    println("END")
  }

}
```

**EDIT:** the problem seems to be related to the Spark application. If I run simple application just for testing JSON unmarshalling everything goes OK. But if I try to do the same from the Spark application, then the problem appears as described above. Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting your code in a package.

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta Like throwing `JsonUtil`, `Person` and `Main` in some common package?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta Just tried and the problem persist. Same exceptions.

Comment: I can run your codes without exception on latest Spark trunk. What Spark version you use? 1.2.1?

Comment: "scalaVersion := "2.11.4". From the Spark 1.2.1 page: "For the Scala API, Spark 1.2.1 uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.10.x)."

Comment: @Paul The Spark distribution I have, is the one built from sources (1.2.1) following instructions for building for Scala 2.11. The mistake can be originated because of this anyway?

Comment: i assumed you were using the distributed files, not building from source, since your question didn't say otherwise. I think it might be an idea to try it with the prebuilt files (and scala 2.10.x) - then you'll know if it's a library/version problem. The other questions (where the issue was a version conflict) do seem to describe something similar to your situation

Comment: @Paul Downgraded to scala 2.10.4 and prebuilt spark 1.2.1 and the problem disappeared. Thanks a lot))